# How to recognize input combination?

Tags: c++, input, combinations, sfml

I am trying to create a function that allows me to recognize some input combination, something like street fighter's (or other fighting game) combination (down, down+right, right + punch=hadoken), for my videogame.
My idea is to put the input into a stack and then recognize the combination.
The problem is:
When the game loop is running and you press a key only for a while the game will recognize X times your input (X = number of cycle passed while you pressed the key).
I have tried to limit the number of input with a timer but it not seems a good solution.

Any idea?

Comment: Keep track of when the key changes state and store key-down events.

Answer (score 0):

A combination is a sequence of key events. Thus you can have some kind of pointer/iterator to the current event of the sequence and then when you get a new `sf::Event` from your window you update the pointer/iterator: if it doesn't match the next one, you reset the pointer/iterator, otherwise you increment it. If you reach the last event of the sequence you have a valid combination.

Here is some pseudo code that might make it more clear:

```
class Combo
{
    sequence events;
    iterator it = events.begin();
    bool handle(event e)
    {
        if (e == *it)
        {
            if (it == events.end())
            {
                it = events.begin();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                ++it;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            it = events.begin();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

void Manager::update(event e) // or whatever class you have
{
    sequence combos = ...;
    for (c : combos)
    {
        if (c.handle(e))
        {
            // perform combo 'c'
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't need any timer or stack.

Comment: It seems a good idea; I have read this "Smooth movements can only be achieved by using real-time keyboard input with sf::Keyboard", in SFML documentation.
Do you think it may be correct to use sf::Keyboard to move characters and use sf::Event for handling combos ?

Comment: I guess you're refering to [this tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php#the-keypressed-and-keyreleased-events). Be careful not to misinterpret what it means. [Here](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/483) is a short discussion that might give you more insight, especially Kynnath's comment. Anyway, go with the method you find the easiest and if the result are not satisfying enough try another one.

Comment: Uhm I was unaware about this fact.
Good to know.
Thank you very much.